# Request filtering icon is missing

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have added the request filtering role to my server (Windows Sever 2008). I have installed the administrator pack, but I have not restarted the computer. The icon is still missing.

Comment: Are you talking about the Server administrator pack for Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [article here](http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/enabling-the-request-filtering-ui-), but in windows 2008 you need to do both:

1. install the IIS Request Filtering feature from Roles in Server
   Administrator  and
2. Add the [IIS admin pack](http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack) for the icon to    appear in the IIS
   Admin Console